# composer.json - minimum-stability for single package

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I had this problem that whenever i wanted to download `dev-master` running `$ composer require egeloen/google-map-bundle dev-master` package I was getting error:

> Problem 1
>
> - Installation request for egeloen/google-map-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by egeloen/google-map-bundle[dev-master].
> - egeloen/google-map-bundle dev-master requires egeloen/google-map ^2.0@dev -> satisfiable by egeloen/google-map[2.0.x-dev] but these
>     conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

When I added `minimum-stability: "dev"` to composer.json file it suddenly upgraded all the packages including symfony/symfony to `dev-master`. I am not getting any error, but I am worried that I might have problems with some unstable packages in the future.

I made some research and found out that it is possible to set `minimum-stability` to single package. I tried running this:

```
$ composer require egeloen/google-map-bundle dev-master@dev
```

But unfortunatelly I am getting an error:

> Problem 1
>
> - egeloen/google-map-bundle dev-master requires egeloen/google-map ^2.0@dev -> satisfiable by egeloen/google-map[2.0.x-dev].
>
>   - egeloen/google-map-bundle dev-master requires egeloen/google-map ^2.0@dev -> satisfiable by egeloen/google-map[2.0.x-dev].
>   - Removal request for egeloen/google-map == 2.0.9999999.9999999-dev
>   - Installation request for egeloen/google-map-bundle dev-master@dev -> satisfiable by
>       egeloen/google-map-bundle[dev-master].

Unfortunatelly it suggests `^2.0@dev`, but that version is not what I need. Any ideas where I am wrong or what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bundle you want to install has another dependency `egeloen/google-map` with a constraint of `^2.0@dev` (also don't confuse this package with the bundle package). Since there is no stable `2.0` release of this dependency yet, it fails when your minimum stability is `stable`.

To resolve it without lowering the minimum stability for the other packages, you should explicitely list `egeloen/google-map` in your dependencies:

```
"egeloen/google-map": "^2.0@dev"
```

This will allow Composer to install a non-stable version of this "second-level" dependency.

Comment: In other words if I install this package I can install bundle of dev-master without defining minimum-stability for it?

Comment: No, if the bundle has no stable version, you need to specify `dev-master` or `@dev` there as well.

Comment: Perfect it is working as you said: "egeloen/google-map": "^2.0@dev", "egeloen/google-map-bundle": "dev-master" in composer.json is working fine. Thank you.